# Binding source does not reflect external changes to the database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a table `Table1` with a single varchar `Field1` and the following content:

```
Andy
Bob 
Chris
Dave
```

Now consider the following code, that uses a linq-to-sql datacontext:

```
private DataContext dc = new DataContext();
private BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
private string filter = "";

private void search()
{
    IQueryable<Table1> tbl = dc.Table1;

    if (filter != "") tbl = tbl.Where(x => x.Field1.Contains(filter));

    bs.DataSource = tbl;

    dump(tbl);
}

private void remove()
{
    bs.RemoveAt(3);
    bs.EndEdit();
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}

private void dump(IQueryable<Table1> q)
{
    foreach (var v in q)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(v.Field1);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(q.Count());
    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");

    foreach (Table1 v in bs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(v.Field1);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(bs.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("==========================================================================");
}
```

I call `search()` the first time; this is the (expected) output:

```
Andy
Bob
Chris
Dave
4
--------------------------------
Andy
Bob
Chris
Dave
4
```

Then I call `remove()` and `search()` again. So far so good:

```
Andy
Bob
Chris
3
--------------------------------
Andy
Bob
Chris
3
```

Now I add Dave again to the database *from outside the app*, and run `search()` one more time:

```
Andy
Bob
Chris
Dave
4
--------------------------------
Andy
Bob
Chris
3
```

At this point `bs` does not reflect the actual content of the `dc`.

I tried many combinations of `bs.ResetBindings()`, `bs.EndEdit()`, `dc.Refresh()`, without success.

Table entries are passed between different functions, edited, deleted, ecc.: this is the reason why my datacontext is shared between the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

> this is the reason why my datacontext is shared between the whole code.

Unfortunately I think it is also the reason for this behaviour and I think you may have to think carefully about where and how you reuse a long-lived DataContext as this can sometimes be dangerous.

The problem arises because the DataContext implements a cache and sometimes the cache is used and sometimes it isn't.

You can avoid **this** particular issue by changing your search routine to create a new DataContext, but that does not solve any other problems you might encounter such as stale data , increased memory usage or SubmitChanges slowing down etc.

You can replicate this issue and perhaps see more details with the following LinqPad script which shows the internal cachedList

```
private TypedDataContext dc;
private BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    
void Main()
{
    search("First Search", false);

    bs.RemoveAt(3);
    bs.EndEdit();
    dc.SubmitChanges();

    this.ExecuteCommand(@"DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = 'Dave' INSERT INTO[Table1]([Field1]) VALUES(@p0)");

    search("Second Search reusing Context", false);
    search("Third Search using new DataContext", true);
}
        
private void search(string desc, bool createNewDataContext )
{
    dc = createNewDataContext ? new TypedDataContext() : this ; 
    
    IQueryable<Table1> tbl = dc.Table1;

    var cachedList = tbl.Uncapsulate().cachedList; 
    
    bs.DataSource = tbl;
    var differences = Util.Dif(tbl, bs);

    (new { cachedList, differences.IsSame, differences  }).Dump(desc);
}
```

which produces the results

[image]

As you can see the second result is incorrect, but the third, using a new DataContext, is correct.